# Difference between CompareStr and '=' for Strings in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I just want to know the difference between `CompareStr` and `=` for comparing strings in Delphi. Both yield the same result.

```
if(str2[i] = str1[i]) then
  ShowMessage('Palindrome')

if(CompareStr(str2[i], str1[i]) = 0) then
  ShowMessage('Palindrome')
```

Both show message Palindrome.

Comment: The question is about comparing strings, but judging by the code presented you are comparing chars. Difficult to tell what have been asked here.

Comment: @Serg +1 Good point, I'd assumed that `str1` and `str2` were arrays of string. But maybe not.....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `CompareStr` not when you just want to see whether two strings are equal, but when you want to know how one string compares relative to another. It will return a value less than 0 if the first argument appears first, asciibetically, and it will return a value greater than zero if the first argument belongs *after* the second.

Without `CompareStr`, you might have code like this:

```
if str1[i] = str2[i] then begin
  // They're equal
end else if str1[i] < str2[i] then begin
  // str1 comes first
end else begin
  // str2 comes first
end;
```

That compares `str1` and `str2` twice. With `CompareStr`, you can cut out one of the string comparisons and replace it with a cheaper integer comparison:

```
x := CompareStr(str1[i], str2[i]);
if x = 0 then begin
  // They're equal
end else if x < 0 then begin
  // str1 comes first
end else begin
  // str2 comes first
end;
```

[As Gerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452400/difference-between-comparestr-and-for-strings-in-delphi/6453171#6453171) explains, the function is particularly useful in sorting functions, especially since it has the same interface as other comparison functions like `CompareText` and `AnsiCompareStr`. The sorting function is a [*template method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), and each of the functions serves as a comparison [*strategy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

If all you want to do is test for equality, use the `=` operator — it's easier to read. Use `CompareStr` when you need the extra functionality it provides.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Str1 and Str2 are strings, rather than arrays (or lists) or string, the first version will be more efficient, as the second version will first copy `str1[i]` and `str2[i]` to two new strings, then call a function, with the associated overhead.

The first version will simply compare the single characters referred to by str1[i] and str2[i]

If you are only interested if strings are the same, use `=`. If you need to know if strings are the same, OR which string is greater, then use `CompareStr`.

CompareStr is particularly useful when sorting lists, e.g, with `TList.Sort(CompareFunc)` or `TStringList.Sort(CompareFunc)`

If you want case-insensitive comparisons, use CompareText.

Comment: +1 for `CompareText`. Case insensitivity will probably be the most imporant reason not to use `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The result is not the same when compared strings are not equal. The result of CompareStr or AnsiCompareStr is of Integer type showing some more information literally how those strings compare. Take a look at http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=AnsiCompareStr

Comment: thats it? only the result type is different? Then it is pretty much same i guess

Comment: If I recall correctly `==` used to call `CompareStr` in earlier versions of Delphi.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Delphi has never supported non-Pascal operators like ==.

Comment: @Gerry Obviously I meant the comparison operator `=`.

Comment: @Chaos - sorry, thought you meant as an additional operator like === in some languages. <troll>(possibly symptomatic of a poor design?)</troll>

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the return value (integer versus boolean), from the code it says that for CompareStr "the compare operation is based on the 8-bit ordinal value of each character and is not affected by the current user locale". So it looks like CompareStr was originally part of the FastCode routines and is in essence an optimised Ansi version developed for performance reasons. I have always tended to go with "=", "<", ">", etc.

Comment: CompareStr was not originally from FastCode. It was originally Turbo Pascal. Delphi added AnsiCompareStr to account for different code pages. FastCode improved CompareStr.