# Is = a case sensitive or insensitive comparison of strings in Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi

I just wonder whether

```
if (str1 = str2) then
```

perform a case sensitive or insentisive comparision. I search on google but only find this [Difference between CompareStr and '=' for Strings in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452400/difference-between-comparestr-and-for-strings-in-delphi)

Comment: You know you can do a simple test to get the answer, right?

Comment: @Olivier, Thank you very much for your advice. I just forget to write a code to test it. I just try to find the help document and online article but cannot find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Relational_Operators) tells us:

> Strings are compared according to the ordinal values that make up the
> characters that make up the string.

`'A'` and `'a'` are different symbols, with different ordinal values, so comparison is case-sensitive, of course.

There are special functions like `CompareText` for insensitive comparisons. Note that case-insensitivity is especially emphasized in descriptions.

Comment: It also means [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) aren't equal either: [`A` (U+0041)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A) is neither [`Α` (U+0391)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha) nor [`А` (U+0410)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic))